# Visual Studio Refuses to link d3d11.lib without pragma comment

Tags: c++, direct3d

I thought that you are able to use the Property Pages -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies to list all of the libraries you want to link. Is this not accurate? I added the following to my additional dependencies list:

```
d3d11.lib
d3dcompiler.lib
dxgi.lib
dxguid.lib
```

I have some super basic code for initializing d3d11:

```
bool init_direct3d()
{
    UINT create_device_flags = 0;
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    create_device_flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL feature_level;
    ID3D11Device* d3d_device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* immediate_context;

    const HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, create_device_flags, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &d3d_device, &feature_level, &immediate_context);
    if ( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"D3D11CreateDevice Failed.", nullptr, 0);
        return false;
    }

    if ( feature_level != D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 )
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Direct3D Feature Level 11 unsupported", nullptr, 0);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I'm getting linker errors

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: UGH_Assets, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>UGH_Assets.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D11CreateDevice@40 referenced in function "bool __cdecl init_direct3d(void)" (?init_direct3d@@YA_NXZ)
1>D:\repos\Perforce\orange_project\UGH_Tools\UGH_Assets\Debug\UGH_Assets.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "UGH_Assets.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What's interesting is that the linker error goes away if I link using a pragma comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")`

Why is it requiring me to use a pragma comment? I had the understanding that the additional dependencies list was a separate way of adding libraries without using pragma comment? This has always worked for me when doing other projects in Qt for example. Does anyone know why it does not work for direct3d 11 libraries? I also tried adding an absolute path in the additional dependencies list and this also did not work.

Comment: Did you add those dependencies to the correct (or all) configuration(s)?

Comment: ... and did you add the 4 files as a semi-colon delimited list? (Or at least, do they *show* as semi-colon delimited in the simple edit view?)

Comment: Hey there, thanks for responding. They show up as semicolon separated in the property page. However, they are only new lined in the edit menu (this has always worked for me in the past). I did add the libraries to all configurations. I'm currently using a debug configuration, and x64.

Actually, I just realized my visual studio was set to use x86... Are there separate x86 and x64 libs I should setup? Seems to work when I go to x64.

Comment: Yes. You have to set for all/each configuration **and** "platform". The settings are specific to both. And, also yeah - the list shows a semi-colon delimited in the single-line view but, when you go into the actual edit box, they are on new lines.

Comment: I agree with Adrian. The problem you are having is likely that you are not setting that for All Configurations and All Platforms. BTW, Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Hi Chuck, i was able to get it to work. It was just a little confusing as a blank win32 template uses x86 configuration by default. When I changed it to x64 everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When editing the project settings in a Visual Studio project, be sure you are setting **All Configurations** and **All Platforms**:

[image]

> You may want to check out the [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates) and [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).